# Frontend custom post submission results in wp_insert_post() undefined

Tags: ajax, wordpress, frontend, custom-post-type

I've been struggling for a few days with this issue and I really hope you can help me out.

I've created a plugin, which is located in:

'/wp-content/plugins/my-cool-plugin'.

My plugin allows users to post a custom post type via a form on a public page, basically anyone should be able to post something.
Using jQuery, I listen to when my frontend form is submitted and using Ajax I pass the data from the form to a php file to process it into a post.
This file is located at:

'/wp-content/plugins/my-cool-plugin/inc/processor.php'.

Below is the content of my processor file:

```
$var1= $_POST['some'];
$var2= $_POST['data'];

$new_post = array(
    'post_type'         => 'my_custom_post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'mcp_1'             => $var1,
    'mcp_2'             => $var2
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post, $wp_error );
if ($wp_error == 'false'){
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
    echo $post_url;
}else {
    // some sort of error
}
```

When I test my form, it results in the following error:

Call to undefined function wp_insert_post() on line ... which is the following line:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post, $wp_error );
```

Do I need to include something since I'm not in the WordPress 'scope' anymore?
Or is there another (much better) way for inserting custom posts from a front end form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to process Nick's answer, but I finally got it to work! Like Nick said, I dropped using the process file because is was out of the scope of WordPress. I moved my post creation from my proces file to a new function in the plugin init file (my-cool-plugin.php), as Nick suggested. This resulted in the following new function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_coolplugin_create_post', 'coolplugin_create_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_coolplugin_create_post', 'coolplugin_create_post');

function coolplugin_create_post() {
    $var1 = $_POST['some'];
    $var2 = $_POST['data'];

    $new_post = array(
        'post_type'         => 'my_custom_post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish'
        'post_title'        => 'Some title'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post, $wp_error );

    // check if there is a post id and use it to add custom meta
    if ($post_id) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'mcp_1', $var1);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'mcp_2', $var2);
    }

    if ($wp_error == false){
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        echo $post_url;
    }else {
        // some sort of error
    }
}
```

I also had to change the way I inserted my custom values into the newly created post, because the `wp_insert_post()` function only accepts default post parameters (see the [wp_insert_post documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) for these parameters).

Next to my insert/create post function I also had to make some adjustments to my javascript file, which retrieves the filled in data from my form. Therefore (as Nick suggested) I needed to pass my Ajax URL from PHP to JS by adding the following function to `my-cool-plugin.php` like this:

```
function your_plugin_ajaxurl() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var coolPluginAjaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    </script>
<?php }

add_action('wp_head','your_plugin_ajaxurl');
```

By adding the `coolPluginAjaxUrl` variable to the head I'm able to use the URL in my javascript to post the data to when my form is submitted, like this:

```
$( '#form' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
    var request;

    e.preventDefault();
    var val_one = $( '#val-one' ).val();
    var val_two = $( '#val-two' ).val();

    var formData = {
        action: 'coolplugin_create_post',
        some: val_one,
        data: val_two,
    };

    request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: coolPluginAjaxUrl,
        data: formData,
    });
});
```

The `formData` holds the `coolplugin_create_post` action defined in PHP and the request is posted to the `coolPluginAjaxUrl` URL, defined in the head.

Thanks Nick for pointing me into the right direction and I hope that my solution will also help others. Please note that I've stripped my code of several security measures for others to easily understand how the code works.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running the file out of wordpress scope? That is not the best practive. Instead you could run it in wordpress scope and user wordpress native ajax.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_yourplugin_create_post', 'yourplugin_create_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_yourplugin_create_post', 'yourplugin_create_post');

function yourplugin_create_post() {
 // your code here
}
```

Then you would need your ajax url to be passed from php to js:

```
function your_plugin_ajaxurl() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var yourPluginAjaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_head','your_plugin_ajaxurl');
```

Then you can use your ajax request but you would need to indicate action:yourplugin_create_post and url = yourPluginAjaxUrl

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your reply. It helped me a lot in finding my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
```

Comment: My file isn't in the WordPress scope, therefore the `wp-load.php` file is being looked for in the folder of the file that requires the `wp-load.php` file. Meaning that the require looks for the `wp-load.php` in my `/wp-content/plugins/my-cool-plugin/inc/` folder.